# how to position a string character in R

Tags: string, r

Suppose I have a string like:

`x<-c("bv_bid_bayley_inf_development_f7r","bv_fci_family_care_indicator_f7r")`

how can I position the first `"_"` (a) and the last `"_"` (b) so that I can `substr(x,a,b)` in R. Such a output like that:

```
bid_bayley_inf_development
fci_family_care_indicator
```

Comment: It would help if you tell us what you're hoping to get.

Comment: Are you trying to find the position of the underscores?

Comment: Yes, I detailed my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to extract the substring:

```
x <- c("bv_bid_bayley_inf_development_f7r", "bv_fci_family_care_indicator_f7r")

sub("[^_]*_(.*)_[^_]*", "\\1", x)
# [1] "bid_bayley_inf_development" "fci_family_care_indicator"
```

Answer (score 1):

for position only,

```
gregexpr("_",x)
```